# How does angular material disable global scroll on dropdown focus?

Tags: angular, angular-material

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

On dropdown open, the global scroll is disabled. However, no position property of `<html>` or `<body>` was changed, the global scroll bar was also present.

Comment: It uses overlay with `BlockScrollStrategy` to stop scrolling

Comment: @KathakDabhi I think it does not. `BlockScrollStrategy` will add `position: fixed` to body. Didn't see that in angular's page.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#scroll-strategies

Answer (score 2):

It is because the select drop down body is implemented with overlays in angular.

This overlay opens up on the  complete window kindof blocking access to the  underling html content.

You can inspect the html and see a overlay container inside body tag.

Once you open the select drop down and try inspecting on the screen it will be inside this overlay container